# How To Make My WD My Passport External Hard Drive "Public"?

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

I have a WD My Passport External Hard Drive.

I'm not sure what I did, but I just played around with the 'security' thing on the properties. My problem is this: I can not open this hard drive on other computers!

It can only be opened on my laptop.

When I plug it on other computers/laptops, it just shows NTFS. I cannot access it on other computers.

When I go to 'properties', I don't know how to make this hard drive public, or make it accessible to other computers.

I hope you can help me on this. Your ideas will be very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you've enabled the encryption feature often found on WD drives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you borked your security settings.  Depending on what you did, it may be easy to fix.  The answer will depend on what you changed.

But lets start with:

In the security tab, make sure `Everyone` has `Full Control`

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the drive in Computer and go to Properties. Under the sharing tab, hit Advanced Sharing, then tick Share This Folder, click permissions, and set everyone to Full Control. Failing that, there should always be an administrative share available for anyone on remote machines who are listed as local admins of the machine you need to access. You can access it by typing \Machinename\Driveletter$ in search in the start menu.